# Prevent input field from converting dot to comma

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, input-field

This might be a very simple problem to solve, but cant find the answer anywhere.
So, i am creating a Chrome extension. Here i am trying to insert a value into a number field. This should be no problem, but somehow and for some reason my dot is being replaced by a comma. I have tried used, as u see string, but also int. Please take a look at the picture. Thanks in advance.

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNsKx.gif)

Comment: A comma is used in Europe (and likely other locales) as opposed to a decimal so I'm guessing that could be related to your issue. Maybe the server is based in Europe?

Comment: That could be the problem yes, I dont know how to nudge this.

Comment: I don't believe there really **is** a solution to this... outside of moving the server. Honestly the more I think about it, I don't think it's the server, it's the location of the client browser. Are you in Europe? Are you on a VPN that's in Europe?

Answer (score -1):

Hello Jason welcome to stackoverflow have you tried  adding changing the language for your input in your code ?

for example: 
`<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" lang="en">`

see http://nimbupani.com/declaring-languages-in-html-5.html

Comment: Thank for your answer. I cant make theese kind of changes to the DOM tree it seems.